# Custom page size for POS printer

Tags: html, css, angular

My POS printer paper width is 3in,I am not using any custom paper size in css, content fits to the paper correcctly, but I see some padding on top of every page.By the way I want entire content in single page. Any help is appreciated.

I tried with custom page size, with no use.

```
      <style>
        @media print {
          body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        html {
          height: 100%;
        }
        body {
          min-height: 100%;
        }

          div {
           orphans: 5;
           widows: 5;
           }

          @media only print{

           div{
             page-break-inside: avoid;
            }
         }
      </style>
<body onload="window.print();window.close()" class="bill">
<section class="sheet">
${printContents}
```

[Top padding on every page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjHL8.png)

Comment: You don't provide enough CSS to reproduce it... give us something to work with

Comment: I tried with  @page { size: 76mm auto }
          body.bill .sheet {  width: 76mm; height: auto } /* sheet size */ .Please go through the image, Top padding on every page.Also I want all the content in single page.

Comment: I used to use this `html, body, .page { display: block; width: 210mm; height: unset; margin: 0}`, but I can't help much more...

Comment: Thanks Akxe, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you púrovide the actual example? HTML + CSS, or link?